# Ascensor.js is not working properly on iPad & iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

How can i fix this **Ascensor.js** problem on **ipad** & **iphone**?
you can see the problem on this site: http://www.tepekaninsaat.com/test

Comment: Please tell us what the problem is, and, if possible, tell us what you've tried to do to fix it.

Comment: @jwrush the problem; ascensor.js is not working on ipad & iphone

Answer (score 2):

I will leave this answer here in case anyone happens to be in the same problem than me.

Use this : [gesture jquery plugin QuoJS](http://quojs.tapquo.com/api/)

And then you can do something like this:

```
//QuoJS gesture    
$$('#mama').swipeLeft(function(){
        doit();
    }); 

function doit()
{
   $('.ascensorLinkNext:first').trigger('click');

}
```

I created a "button" with the class provided in the api for ascensor.js so I forced the click on it when a the gesture is triggered.

This is my first contribution. I hope I did it ok.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to work at all on Ipad(s) (and android tablets for that matter)

What I did is disabled it for touch devices using modernizr :

in the html

```
<script src="ascensor/js/modernizr.2.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(before the call to jquery)

Then in myscript.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (Modernizr.touch){ // detion of touch
        // do nothing
        // should try to find a way to load an alternate 
        // stylesheet for ipads/android here
    } else {
        // load ascensor
        $('#content').ascensor({
            ...
        });
    }
 });
```

That does not make ascensor working on ipad, but at least you monopage site
is readable again :)

Edit :

Another solution, would be to use a meta tag :

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=0,width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
```

But, if it solves (mostly) the display problem, the navigation (at least on an Android tablet where i tested it) is still a little shaky and faulty, depending on the shape of your map)